R Markdown - is there a way to use the legend/caption formatting from kable() to another plot?
I'm using the formating kable_paper("hover") for a table that I found here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html
The caption for that table has a lighter/grey-ish colour and smaller size, and I would like to apply this formatting to the rest of the captions in the document (generated plots with ggplot, etc). So, in this figure, I would want the caption of Figure 4 to have the same formatting as the one of Table 1:

Is this possible, or do I have to format the captions in another way?

Since your are having HTML as output format, you can adjust formating through css.
